# SQLAlchemy reverse ordered query

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

What the best way to reverse ordered query? Can I do it only with sql/sqlalchemy?
For example if
I have rows with ids: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ,7, 8, 9, 10]
I want to fetch rows **after id 5** with **limit 3** in order like that [8, 7, 6]

For now it works with:

```
Comment.query.filter(Comment.id > 5).order_by(Post.id.asc()).limit(3)
```

I got list with ids [6, 7, 8]
and after I use **list.reverse()** in Python to get list with order [8,7,6]

This doesn't work:
`Comment.query.filter(Comment.id > 5).order_by(Post.id.desc()).limit(3)`
it will give list with ids [10,9,8]

Comment: It is normal that your second script does not work: It asks to fetch the three biggest ids superior to 5. If you had ids like : 1002, 1001, 1000 being the biggest available, these would be the one that you wound get. If you are sure that ids 6,7 and 8 exist, you could : Comment.query.filter(Comment.id <=8).order_by(Post.id.desc()).limit(3)

Comment: @MatinaG Thanks for answer, yup, I tried this before, with Comment.query.filter(Comment.id <= after_id + limit ).order_by(Post.id.desc()).limit(3), but in table comments not only for one post, and for one post we have ids like [ 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 15 ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use CTE.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.HasCTE.cte

apply the limit:

```
cte = session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.id > 5).limit(3).cte()
```

then reverse

```
result = session.query(cte).order_by(cte.c.id.desc()).all()
```

Comment: cte = db.session.query(Comment).filter(Comment.id > 5).limit(3).cte(); res = db.session.query(cte).order_by(cte.c.id.desc()).all(). This code throw TypeError: Boolean value of this clause is not defined

Answer (score -1):

To address this you can use this thingy after you assign your results :

```
results = Comment.query.filter(Comment.id > 5).order_by(Post.id.asc()).limit(3)
```

you do this

```
results_sorted = sorted(results, key=lambda x: x.id)
```

Comment: The OP is already knew about this (they were using `list.reverse()`, which is effectively the same).